# Which musical piece is this from Code Geass?

Tags: music, code-geass

This tune is from R2 episode 23, near 19:20 mark in the version I have, though it is played many times in the series.

The tune plays at 7:15 in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bimxAEWXzfU).

Does anyone know which musical piece this is?

Answer (score 1):

It's an unreleased piece from the soundtrack called **Path of Decisions**. You can find it here:

[Code Geass: Unreleased Album - 30 Path of Decisions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yi88NrNYA1I&list=PLb4mticUuCmQSnQpXJDttkzbhOxAdnGWf&index=30)